# Loss report, check if user is on the following step and has same CampaignSource, if so display it

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine the current dataset

| Steps | CampaignSource | set_UserId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Pot | a,b,c,d,e |
| Two | Pot | a,b,c,d |
| Three | Pot | a,b,c |
| One | Daddy | e,f,g,h |
| Two | Daddy | e,f,g |
| Three | Daddy | e,f |

From this dataset you need to build a df, that display the loss users. The ones who are in the first step but not in the second, and so on

Desired result,

| Steps | CampaignSource | set_UserId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Pot | e |
| Two | Pot | d |
| One | Daddy | h |
| Two | Daddy | g |

Things worth noting, when the set of UserIds, differ in CampaignSource. You need to stop so you avoid comparison beetween different CampaignSources.

My attempt at this issue was as follow:

```
loss_dict = {
    'Steps':[],
    'UserId':[],
    'CampaignSource':[]
}

for a in camp_df['CampaignSource'].unique():
    temp_df = camp_df.loc[camp_df['CampaignSource'] == a].reset_index(drop=True)
    # The dataset is ordered, i just could make it work in ordered manner
    for b,c in enumerate(zip(temp_df['UserId'],temp_df['Steps'],temp_df[['CampaignSource']])):
        try:    
            loss_dict['Steps'].append(c[1])
            loss_dict['UserId'].append(temp_df['UserId'][b]-temp_df['UserId'][b+1])
            loss_dict['CampaignSource'].append(c[2])
        except KeyError:
            continue
```

Is worth noting i didnt manage to eliminate the last steps, also my approach is a little too convulated, and i am looking for alternatives. Would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to solve it, without the use of FOR loop and taking your dataframe as is, and a very concise (non verbose) solution

REVISED SOLUTION: Difference appears with the first row

```
df['diff']= df.assign(prev_id  = df['set_UserId'].shift(-1) ,
                      prev_src = df['CampaignSource'] == df['CampaignSource'].shift(-1)
                     ).apply(lambda row: set(row['set_UserId']).difference(set(row['prev_id']))
                             if row['prev_src'] 
                             else "", axis=1).astype(str).replace(r'{|}|\'','', regex=True)
```

```
    Steps   CampaignSource  set_UserId  diff
0   One     Pot             a,b,c,d,e    e
1   Two     Pot             a,b,c,d      d
2   Three   Pot             a,b,c   
3   One     Daddy           e,f,g,h      h
4   Two     Daddy           e,f,g        g
5   Three   Daddy           e,f
```

FIRST SOLUTION: Difference appears with the second row

```
df['diff']= df.assign(prev_id  = df['set_UserId'].shift(1) ,
                      prev_src = df['CampaignSource'] == df['CampaignSource'].shift(1)
                     ).apply(lambda row: set(row['prev_id']).difference(set(row['set_UserId']))
                             if row['prev_src'] 
                             else "", axis=1).astype(str).replace(r'{|}|\'','',regex=True)
```

```
    Steps   CampaignSource  set_UserId  diff
0   One     Pot             a,b,c,d,e   
1   Two     Pot             a,b,c,d       e
2   Three   Pot             a,b,c         d
3   One     Daddy           e,f,g,h     
4   Two     Daddy           e,f,g         h
5   Three   Daddy           e,f           g
```

here is how it works, two temporary columns are introduced which essentially are the previous rows values, one is for set_userid and other is to check if CampaignSource has changed. then a set notation is used to find the difference b/w the previous and next value. Since you need the values, and returned result from lambda is a set, parenthesis are removed.

Comment: Nice one.  I am gonna try to apply it and i will return if it is correct or not

Comment: Well there is only one issue with your solution, the differential beetween the columns, Should be situated on the first row for example in the case one two from the campaignsource pot. The diff, should be e at index 0. Despite that i think it was a very interesting approach

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1, added the second solution to have the difference with the first row. earlier solution is also there.  Thanks for trying it out and sharing the feedback. really appreciate it!  Best

Answer (score 1):

Check if the following could be applied to you problem.
First we map the categorical column "Steps" to int. Then we group and shift each of the groups in order to get the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd

map_order = {"One": 1, "Two": 2, "Three": 3}

df = pd.DataFrame([['One','Pot',set(['a','b','c','d','e'])],
                   ['Two','Pot',set(['a','b','c','d'])],
                   ['Three','Pot',set(['a','b','c'])],
                   ['One','Daddy',set(['e','f','g','h'])],
                   ['Two','Daddy',set(['e','f','g'])],
                   ['Three','Daddy',set(['e','f'])]],
                  columns=['Steps','CampaignSource','set_UserId'])

df["Steps"] = df["Steps"].map(map_order)
df = df.sort_values(['Steps','CampaignSource'])

final_df = []
for _, df_g in df.groupby(["CampaignSource"]):
    df_g["set_UserId_prev"] = df_g.shift(-1)["set_UserId"]
    df_g["diff"] = df_g["set_UserId"] - df_g["set_UserId_prev"]
    final_df.append(df_g)
    
out_df = pd.concat(final_df).dropna()
out_df

Steps   CampaignSource  set_UserId      set_UserId_prev diff
1       Daddy           {g, e, h, f}    {g, e, f}       {h}
2       Daddy           {g, e, f}       {e, f}          {g}
1       Pot             {e, d, a, b, c} {b, d, c, a}    {e}
2       Pot             {b, d, c, a}    {b, c, a}       {d}
```